# NodeJS, MySQL query with quotes

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can't add to the database because the contained character is included

```
var names = {
    name: "Hi' test work"
}
mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO test (names) VALUES (" + JSON.stringify(names || []) + ")", function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('success');
    }
    process.exit();
});
```

sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'test work"}\')\' at line 1'

Comment: Use **placeholder values** whenever possible. This code has huge [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're using JSON string encoding for what should be SQL string encoding. The two are considerably different. [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org) and many other database drivers for Node support placeholder values. See the [escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) section of the documentation for examples.

Comment: Additionally, if you're new to Node, I'd strongly advise looking at promises and `async`/`await`. This avoids the callback nesting problem and error propagation is a lot easier.

Comment: mysqlConnection.escape Help, thanks

Comment: No, don't use the escape function unless you absolutely must. Always steer towards **placeholder values**. This is extremely important to understand because the consequences of forgetting to escape can be catastrophic.

Comment: In my case it is safe, such signs occur once in 500 results = once a month

Comment: "It won't happen to me" is false confidence.